# How to disable autocomplete on macOS but not iOS?

Tags: macos, ios, auto-complete

How do I disable autocomplete on macOS Sierra for MacBook, please, without disabling it on iOS 10 for iPhone?

Seems to occur only in native/Apple apps. Appears below my typing as blue text in a white rectangle with a close button on its right.

It flashes for a split second before inserting its suggestion into my typing, without feedback from me.

The suggestions are listed in Syst Prefs / Keyboard / Text / Replace…With. These I created on my phone's device Settings / General / Keyboard / Text Replacement, but I never asked for them to be applied to macOS. How'd they get there?

If I delete them from the Mac, they also delete from the phone. How might I remove/disable them from one but not the other? Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

### Explanation

The text replacements in `System Preferences > Keyboard > Text` (macOS) and `Settings > General > Keyboard > Text Replacement` (iOS) are tightly integrated into iCloud.

In fact, both sync using iCloud and are stored in your iCloud Drive (com.apple.TextInput). This is an invisible folder.

---

### Disable text replacements on macOS

In order to disable them on your Mac, you have two options:

- iOS: In `Settings > iCloud > iCloud` disable 'iCloud Drive'.
- macOS: In `System Preferences > iCloud > iCloud Drive (Options)` disable 'System Preferences'.

Now you need to delete your text replacements from your Mac. You may create a backup of them by selecting all (CMD+A) and dragging them on your Desktop.

Was this answer helpful?

Comment: If I untick "System Preferences" from "iCloud Drive (Options)", I'd expect that would halt the syncing of all syst prefs across my different Macs.